# How can I uniquely select elements local to my current Blogger post as opposed to elements in the entire document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I'm using elements and defining ids like

```
<div class="button" id="b1">
```

However, this will be an element common to all my posts, which assigns a non-unique id to the elements. Because of this, it's impossible for me to bind javascript/jQuery functions to the specific element like

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
     ...
});
```

since `b1` occurs multiple times in the document. Is there a way to either assign ids unique to the post, or reference elements local to the post?

Comment: IDs should only be used ONCE on a page, so that's something you should change before proceeding. Make it a class, for example.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just looking for something specific to Blogger which allows me to generate these unique ids automatically. For example postid-b1 instead of just b1, where postid automatically gets replaced with the appropriate identifier on parse. The alternative would be to manually edit the code in each post, which seems wrong.

Comment: inspect it in the browser tools - isn't there any class or ID in the wrapper tag of the post that's unique to it?. Then you could use a combined selector like `.first_post .b1`

Comment: Thanks. That works when if I have to manually do it for each post. I was hoping there is a provision that lets me write meta code once and not have to individually search for every post. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement non-unique id's (but it kind of defeats the point of ids if you do).  This works because you are scanning attributes, not id's.

```js
$("[id=b1]").click(function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b1">
  Click me to disappear
</div>

<div id="b1">
  Click me to disappear as well
</div>
```

Comment: I think unique ids is the way to go, but I'm not sure how to implement them without having to manually specify these for each post.
I'm looking for something specific to Blogger which allows me to generate these unique ids automatically. For example postid-b1 instead of just b1, where postid automatically gets replaced with the appropriate identifier on parse.

Comment: I'll added an example if they're all on the same webpage, but why not just use classes with relative selectors?

Comment: Thanks. Classes work too. My only concern is that these need to be assigned in an auto-generated fashion for each post.

Comment: Are you using PHP with a MYSQL database for post management or just an HTML webpage?

Comment: Okay, so if you want to hide per post, then I'd recommend using a containing class and a class called `b`.  Then you can have some event hide the class `b` from the containing class.  It's not worth using unique id's for this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just looking for something specific to Blogger which allows me to generate these unique ids automatically.

Each Blogger post has a unique id. You can retrieve post id inside blog posts widget by this tag:

```
<data:post.id/>
```

To use post id as id attribute use this expression:

```
<div expr:id='&quot;post-&quot; + data:post.id'></div>
```

The result: (*a unique number for each post*)

```
<div id='post-5458788214569'></div>
```

JQuery selector:

```
$("[id*='post-']").click(function(){
     ...
});
```